# Troubles with an integral

Tags: calculus

I'm having some troubles evaluating this integral.
$$\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} \cdot \exp\left({\frac{-1}{2\sigma^2}(\ln(x)-\mu)^2}\right)\,dx$$ I really have no clue. The exercise I'm making says it equals: $\exp(\mu - \sigma^2/2)$. Can anyone help me solve this? Thanks!